# Strange case with crystal report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports CR XI R1 and CR XI R2 in the application. When I run the application in Windows 7 64-bit OS as 32-bit application, crystal reports works perfectly. However, if the same application is installed in Windows 7 32-bit OS, crystal report doesn't work.

Shouldn't it be opposite of the above case? I thought it should run in 32 bit OS and will fail in 64 bit.
Is it a crystal reports issue, or am I doing something wrong?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How does it fail?

Here are a few rules to follow deploying .NET application that uses Crystal Reports:

- You need to install the Crystal Reports Basic Runtime for your OS (32bit or 64bit)
  NOTE: This needs to be done on the host as well after you deploy it. This registers the 
  runtime in the GAC.
- When you import assemblies into your project, make sure that you import them from the
  GAC (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL...) and always use the version 10 assemblies because 
  the setup project doesn't seem to work with any other
- Crystal only works with 32bit (emulated or normal)

This might not fix your issues but it is good to get these out of the way...

Comment: I have installed the application similarly in both the OS. But still crystal reports doesn't work in 32 bit OS. However, it works perfectly in Windows XP 32-bit.